# Traceroute/tracert fails to receive hops return information

Tags: networking, internet, tcp, traceroute, icmp

I noticed that with some routers/gateways
when I issue a traceroute or a tracert in a 'inner' computer
the hops always fail with:

> request timed out

can anybody clarify this?
what information goes out and comes in for each hop??
what should be configured in the router to resolve this???

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two possible cases here:

One: If you are behind a NAT (specifically what the standards call NAPT, or what proprietary Cisco-ese calls "PAT") gateway, and *none* of the hops in your traceroute report proper information, then your NAT gateway code is handling ICMP "Destination Unreachable; Time Exceeded" messages incorrectly. And since "Time Exceeded" messages don't require any special NAT handling than any other "Destination Unreachable" message, your NAT probably isn't handling *any* ICMP "Destination Unreachable" messages correctly. For most NAT implementations, I don't expect this to be a configuration error; it's more likely that your NAT's codebase just does not contain working code for handling these kinds of messages. So while you could try looking in the configuration UI and manual for your NAT gateway to see if you can enable some kind of ICMP handling that's currently disabled, I suspect you won't get anywhere that way, and you'll just have to replace your current NAT implementation with a better one (which might require replacing your router with a better router).

Two: If some of the hops return useful information, but other hops don't, then that means that the routers of the "failing" hops aren't returning ICMP "Destination Unreachable; Time Exceeded" at all. It could be an implementation error (bug), but it is more likely configured not to do that (some sysadmins worry that responding to pings and traceroutes gives away too much information about the network). Since you probably don't own or have any influence over these other routers on other networks far away on the Internet, there's nothing you can do to make those routers send the necessary ICMP messages that allow traceroute to work.

One last thing: This is almost a third case, but it's more like a special case of case #2. If some early hops work but at some point one hop and all further hops fail, it's an indication that a firewall may be dropping all relevant ICMP messages from all further routers. Many corporate/institutional networks have a firewall at the edge of their network that drops many kinds of ICMP messages for (misguided, IMHO) "security" reasons.

Comment: thanks for your answer.. I was trying to get a more TCP/IP technical insight... ?kind of what traceroute sends to target IP... what expects to return.. and how this information is treated... so I can try to reconfigure the routers...